# Activating a Win8 Metro app from the TFS build controller

Tags: tfs, permissions, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a unit testing project written which undeploys a deployed metro app, builds a metro project then redeploys the app and activates it. The app contains QUnit Metro tests and once the tests produce results the unit testing project completes execution.

I have all of this working, however I want to integrate it with a the TFS build controller and I am getting all kinds of permission issues. The build apparently cannot deploy or undeploy the app and cannot activate it. I am achieving deploy and undeploy via powershell script (the build is trying to do the same). The app activation is achieved via an app activator interface.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the build controller needs to be started as an interactive process, otherwise it does not have the rights to start Windows 8 Apps. After I did that everything works like a charm!